# TypeError when sending email in ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, actionmailer

I am trying to set up a mailer in my Rails application that sends an email to users of the system. When I try to send the email, it is getting processed and the completed emails are being put in the log but near the end of the process I am getting the error:

```
TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer):
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:58:in `email'
```

I am not receiving the email so it seems like the error is occurring when the email is being created or delivered.

The following is my configuration and the code calling the email:

**Production.rb**

```
# Mailer Configuration
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address => 'corp-alt-14',  # Local mail server on the network
  :port => 25,
  :openssl_verify_mode => :none
}
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
def email
  user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  UserMailer.welcome_email(user).deliver_now  # Line 58
  render nothing: true   #Ajax request should not update the page
end
```

**user_mailer.rb**

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def welcome_email(user)
    @user = user
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Welcome Test Email')
  end
end
```

**application_mailer.rb**

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "DoNotReply@example.com"
  layout 'mailer'
end
```

**production.log**

```
I, [2015-07-08T15:55:08.569007 #8496]  INFO -- : Started GET "/users/email?user_id=2" for ::1 at 2015-07-08 15:55:08 -0400
I, [2015-07-08T15:55:08.571007 #8496]  INFO -- : Processing by UsersController#email as JS
I, [2015-07-08T15:55:08.571007 #8496]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"user_id"=>"2"}
D, [2015-07-08T15:55:08.572007 #8496] DEBUG -- :   [1m[36mUser Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mEXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT  [users].* FROM [users] WHERE [users].[id] = @0  ORDER BY [users].[id] ASC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY', N'@0 int', @0 = 2[0m  [["id", "2"]]
I, [2015-07-08T15:55:08.575007 #8496]  INFO -- :   Rendered user_mailer/welcome_email.html.erb within layouts/mailer (1.0ms)
I, [2015-07-08T15:55:08.575007 #8496]  INFO -- :   Rendered user_mailer/welcome_email.text.erb within layouts/mailer (0.0ms)
D, [2015-07-08T15:55:08.577007 #8496] DEBUG -- : 
UserMailer#welcome_email: processed outbound mail in 4.0ms
I, [2015-07-08T15:55:08.614007 #8496]  INFO -- : 
Sent mail to evan_frisch@example.com (36.0ms)
D, [2015-07-08T15:55:08.614007 #8496] DEBUG -- : Date: Wed, 08 Jul 2015 15:55:08 -0400
From: DoNotReply@example.com
To: evan_frisch@example.com
Message-ID: <559d801c8d1d7_21301f76380640db@FRISCHE.mail>
Subject: Welcome Test Email
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="--==_mimepart_559d801c8ca07_21301f7638063943";
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit


----==_mimepart_559d801c8ca07_21301f7638063943
Content-Type: text/plain;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

This is a test email.

Hello Evan

----==_mimepart_559d801c8ca07_21301f7638063943
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<html>
  <body>
    <h1>This is a test email</h1>

<p>Hello Evan</p>
  </body>
</html>

----==_mimepart_559d801c8ca07_21301f7638063943--

I, [2015-07-08T15:55:08.615007 #8496]  INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 44ms
F, [2015-07-08T15:55:08.623007 #8496] FATAL -- : 
TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer):
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:58:in `email
```

I am using Ruby 2.0.0 and Rails 4.2.0.

As far as I can see, there is no symbol that is being converted into an integer in my code. I have attempted to debug into the mailer code to see where the error was being raised but I could not find it. I don't know if there is something wrong with the code I have or if my config is incorrectly done. I have confirmed the mail server's name and port so that data is correct at the least. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's in the log when you run in development mode and send an e-mail? And what is code block around this error: "app/controllers/users_controller.rb:58:in `email"?

Comment: And which is line number 58 in users_controller?

Comment: @Deep sorry about that, line number added as a comment

Comment: @ValAsensio I get the same thing running it in development. The code block is the email action in the users_controller, the line number has now been marked.

Comment: Okay. I see the line #. Thanks.

Comment: Don't know the cause of issue but did you try using different smtp settings, try using google mail once and see if it throws the same error or no (just a try)

Comment: @Deep it took a little work with the configuration but I did manage to get it to send an email with Gmail so it does look it like it may be a configuration thing. I'll keep looking down that path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out when you aren't using SSL and do not have an SMTP just setting `:openssl_verify_mode => :none` is not enough. By adding `:enable_starttls_auto => false` my error disappeared and the emails started sending. It normally defaults to true which apparently caused errors with not using a secure user.

To note my final SMTP settings were:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      :address => 'corp-alt-14',
      :port => 25,
      :openssl_verify_mode => :none,
      :enable_starttls_auto => false
  }
```